Need Ubuntu on HP Proliant Gen8 Microserver
I need to erase many SAS HDD´s.
Therefore i use 3 Microservers from HP.
They are all the Proliant Gen 8.
Normaly i go into  the HP Smart Storage Administrator to detect the HDD´s and make them erasable.
I use 3 different SAS Controllers:

HP Smart Array P222
HP Smart Array P410
HP Smart Array P420

But now i have a bunch of HP SAS Drives that the Microservers cannot detect.
My best guess is that the block size of the drives is 520 bit instead of 512.
I found a guide to change that with the Installation of SCSI Drivers. But i need Ubuntu to do it.
Unfortunately i cannot boot Ubuntu.
I always boot from USB Stick so i can use all 4 Cables for the erasing of the drives.
I can boot Parted Magic, Linux Mint and so on on the Microservers.
But i cannot boot Ubuntu, he doesn´t detect the stick.
I found on this Forum some helpful tips but my knowledge of Linux is not very high.
P.s.
I tested it on 2 other Servers.
On a HP Proliant DL380 Gen9 and on a HP Proliant DL360 Gen10. But they have the same problem.
Edit: Why can i boot ab USB Stick with Linux Mint 19 Tricia on HP Microservers but not a USB Stick with Ubuntu.
I tried Ubuntu 18.04, Ubuntu 24, Ubuntu 15 and a Ubuntu Server Version.
All sticks are created with Rufus (Installation Stick). Then i used a HP Computer to install the Linux Versions from the installation USB Stick to another USB Stick. All ISO´s are verified.
All USB Stick with Ubuntu start on normal PC´s.

Ask Ubuntu is a Q&A resource. I don't see a question here just a statement. Please read [ask] then [edit] accordingly. In particular, you should mention (in your edit) which version of Ubuntu you are trying to boot, which USB boot media (Balena Etcher, Ventoy etc) and whether the iso was verified.

This question is similar to: Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I made an edit 2 Days Ago. I hope my question is now more understandable.
